# Directcast & Ctype differences with enums

Tags: vb.net, directcast, ctype

```
 Public Enum Fruit
    Red_Apple = 1
    Oranges
    Ripe_Banana
End Enum
Private Sub InitCombosRegular()
    Dim d1 As New Dictionary(Of Int16, String)
    For Each e In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Fruit))
        d1.Add(CShort(e), Replace(e.ToString, "_", " "))
    Next
    ComboBox1.DataSource = d1.ToList
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

   'This fails
        Dim combo1 = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, Fruit) ' Fails
        'these both work
        Dim combo2 = DirectCast(CInt(ComboBox1.SelectedValue), Fruit) 'works
        Dim combo3 = CType(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, Fruit) 'works
```

Why does the `CType` work and the `DirectCast` does not with the same syntax? Yet if I cast the `selectedValue` to an `int` before I `DirectCast`, then it works

Regards

_Eric

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason why is because `CType` and `DirectCast` are fundamentally different operations.

`DirectCast` is a casting mechanism in VB.Net which allows for only CLR defined conversions.  It is even more restrictive than the C# version of casting because it doesn't consider user defined conversions.

`CType` is a lexical casting mechanism.  It considers CLR rules, user defined conversions and VB.Net defined conversions.  In short it will do anything and everything possible to create a valid conversion for an object to a specified type.

In this particular case you are trying to convert a value to an Enum which does not have a CLR defined conversion and hence it's failing.  The VB.Net runtime however was able to find a lexical conversion to satisfy the problem.

A decent discussion on the differences exists here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289509(VS.71).aspx#vbtchmicrosoftvisualbasicnetinternalsanchor10

Comment: Thanks. What would be the best practice on this? Explicit cast the selectedValue to an int and directcast(#2), or just Ctype(#3)

Comment: I prefer CType whenever I'm dealing with enum values

Comment: @Eric: a DirectCast should be used when an object is of a given type, and you are casting it to that type.  A string is not an Enum, and neither is an integer.  If you want to cast to an integer first, that might make your code more clear, but using DirectCast will just confuse things.